# decode a QRcode image without using the camera

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

guys I am developing an Android app for reading QR codes. I implemented the library ZXing, but I must not use the camera. I need to get a QR code saved as an image and use the functions relating to ZXing decoding QR code stored as images ... any ideas?

I checked the forum but I need something more complete ..: (

Comment: You mean to say you select the image file and then decoding should be done. is it so?

Comment: yes, forgive my English. I have to decode a qrcode without using the camera. snippets of code found in other threads I have not enough .. I need to go step by step :(... ZXing library already downloaded and placed in the workspace.

Comment: let me get clear again. you don't want to use camera and you want to Decode qr code?

Comment: yes. Imagine that you have the qrcode saved as an image file. I need to take them and decode them. I know that there are specific classes ZXing to do this but I need someone to help me

Comment: I have a same problem.
is solved your problem ?
If yes then please guide me.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can decode a QR without using a camera. You have to import the image from the gallery, get the bitmap and pass it to `LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap);`
Here is the code.

```
LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap); 
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
try {
    Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
    String contents = result.getText(); 
    byte[] rawBytes = result.getRawBytes(); 
    BarcodeFormat format = result.getBarcodeFormat(); 
    ResultPoint[] points = result.getResultPoints();
} catch (NotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
} catch (ChecksumException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
} catch (FormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```